# Not getting exact meaning of some appengine code

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I was exploring a project and I came across the following lines in the build.gradle file in the backend module.

Can someone please explain the significance of the following lines:

```
appengine {
    httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    httpPort = 8888
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = false
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = false
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a configuration block for the [gradle-appengine-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin):

From the docs:

> - httpAddress: The IP address for the local development server (if    server is to be accessed from network). Default is localhost.
> - httpPort: The TCP port which local development server should listen    for HTTP requests on (defaults to 8080).
> - downloadSdk: Downloads the Google App Engine SDK defined by the    configuration name appengineSdk and explodes the artifact into
>     ~/.gradle/appengine-sdk (defaults to false). If set to true the given 
>     SDK is used for running all plugin tasks which takes precedence over
>     APPENGINE_HOME and the system property appengine.sdk.root.
>
> Within appengine you can define optional properties in a closure named
>   appcfg:
>
> - oauth2: Use OAuth2 authentication instead of password-based    authentication.
>
> Within appengine you can also define a closure named endpoints:
>
> - getClientLibsOnBuild: Automatically download client libraries before    the war task is called. (defaults to false)
> - getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild: Automatically download discovery docs before    the war task is called. (defaults to false)